# JavaFX play gif image in ImageView

Tags: java, xml, javafx

I see this question asked a lot but I have not seen a very general way of doing it. I am working on a Desktop app in Java Eclipse Oxygen using JavaFX and I have a loader that I want to show whenever and image is loading via http. An image has to be loaded via http when a user clicks on different rows. So I have my loader on top of the image and I just use; `productPreviewLoader.setVisible(true)` to show it or hide it. The loader ImageView in fxml looks like this in GridPane.

```
<GridPane>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" valignment="TOP" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="productPreview" fitHeight="282.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
      <!-- This is the loader-->
      <ImageView fx:id="productPreviewLoader" fitHeight="112.0" fitWidth="136.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" /> 
      <TextFlow fx:id="productPreviewTextFlow" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets right="10.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="30.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="30.0" />
         </padding></TextFlow>
```

And the code that sets up the loader image looks like this;

```
//Set up the product preview image loader
BufferedImage bufferedImage;
File file = new File("resources\\images\\loaders\\img-loader-icon.gif");
try {
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
   productPreviewLoader.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null));
} catch (IOException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}
productPreviewLoader.setVisible(false);
```

The image does not play in the ImageView. If it is not possible please show me another way of doing it. Also I am having a problem to get the ImageView to center the ImageView horizontally in the GridPane row. The GridPane resizes to match the height of it's parent whenever the window is resized. I know this is 2 questions but I would probably have ended up creating 2 questions.

Answer (score 2):

Well you haven't provide a complete example that I can use in order to show the use cases of how you can load an gif image to an ImageView so I will give you a full example :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GifViewerTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        VBox box = new VBox();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

        box.getChildren().add(imageView);

        Button localLoadButton = new Button("Local load");
        Button externalLoadButton = new Button("URL Load");

        localLoadButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            imageView.setImage(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("java.gif").toExternalForm()));
        });

        externalLoadButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            String imageSource = "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/550761/screenshots/1773241/untitled-5.gif";
            try {
                imageView.setImage(createImage(imageSource));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        FlowPane buttonPane = new FlowPane();
        buttonPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttonPane.getChildren().addAll(localLoadButton, externalLoadButton);

        box.getChildren().add(buttonPane);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box, 500, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    private Image createImage(String url) throws IOException {
        // You have to set an User-Agent in case you get HTTP Error 403
        // respond while you trying to get the Image from URL.
        URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)");

        try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream()) {
            return new Image(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

If all your Images are loaded through URLs then why don't you just use a WebViewer and load the URL instead of using an ImageView? If the gif size is not small that will cause a GUI lag until the gif image is loaded from InputStream in that case you should create the loading process to a background thread but as I said you can avoid all that if you just use a WebViewer.

Comment: Looking at this code I see no where you have set the git animation to play. Except you have added buttons to load the image. I am not having problems to load the image. The image just won't play when added to the ImageView. It stays on the first frame.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "play"? When you use the code above and click on the "URL Load" Button you should see the gif Image. The externalLoadButton loads the gif Image to the ImageView through URL. Maybe I didn't understand your goal here..correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The gif image contains an animation. In my code when I use `productPreviewLoader.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null));` The image is just still without animation

Comment: Yes of course. The code above is playing an animated gif image that you can find in this [link](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/550761/screenshots/1773241/untitled-5.gif). In order to play the animated Image you can either load it the way I am doing it from resources or by the URL directly. Are you saying that using the code I had provided you still are not able to see the animation?

Comment: That's strange I think I was over doing it. So just doing `productPreviewLoader.setImage(new Image("file:resources\\images\\loaders\\img-loader-icon.gif"));` should load a playing image. In your answer I don't think this will work for local images `this.getClass().getResource("java.gif").toExternalForm()` I am assuming you're trying to load a local image instead of an image via HTTP.

Comment: Loading the gif locally is working fine for me too. Of course you need to have the image to the correct path in order to load it from resources. In the example above I had placed the gif image to the same directory with the java classes on default package, you should set your full path if you add your images ( and you should) on different directory/package.